# Division BY 0 with functions

Tags: functions

Take the function $\frac{x^2-4x}{x^\frac{1}{2}}$. It is clear that when $x=0$ this function should be undefined. However we can re write this function as $x^\frac{3}{2} - 4x^\frac{1}{2}$, which is defined for all non negative $x$. So this is my question, as the two functions are the same, why is one not defined for $x=0$, while the other is? And even when we use the first way of writing the function, desmos says it's defined for $x=0$ which I think is very strange. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: "as the two functions are the same..". But they are not. One of them is defined for $x=0$ and the other is not. So the functions have different domains. Things will get more complicated (not simpler) if we disregard that.

Comment: When you 'rewrite' the function you use division, which is only defined for non-zero arguments, thus they are only 'the same' for non-zero arguments. What can be said however is that the function has a 'continuous extension'.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers so far. So I'd just like to know for sure, is the first function defined for $x=0$?

Comment: The first function is not defined at $x=0$

Comment: So desmos having the point $(0,0)$ as on the function is incorrect?

Comment: Yes it is incorrect.